# <c:if> doesn't work inside <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jstl, facelets, uirepeat

I have string list named dataSetUris. I tried to make if condition on it. It returns true but I cant print the command buttons.

What is my wrong here? Thanks for help.

```
 <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{result.dataSetUris}">                                           
   <c:if test="${item.length() > 0} ">                                          
     <p:commandButton value="Click" onclick="window.open('#{item}')" ></p:commandButton>        
    </c:if>                                                                                                          
 </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: `<ui:repeat>` is the culprit. The conditional check of `<c:if>` is dependent upon `var` of `<ui:repeat>`, a repeater component. Try the same using `<c:forEach>`. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/1391249), "*Do not bind the `var` of iterating JSF components to JSTL tag attributes*".

Comment: In this case, just conditionally rendering `<p:commandButton>` should be sufficient as the duplicate link indicates - `<p:commandButton rendered=#{item.length() > 0}>` dropping the whole `<c:if>` thing.

Comment: yes this works, as BalusC explained, thanks.